# Validation for select box

Tags: jquery, forms, jquery-validate

I am doing a form validation using jquery. I am not getting how to validate the select list menu.

Could you please help me out with this.

Here is my code and **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/rw9ns/2/)**

```
$.validator.setDefaults({
    submitHandler: function() { alert("submitted!"); }
});

$().ready(function() {
    // validate the comment form when it is submitted
    $("#commentForm").validate();

    // validate signup form on keyup and submit
    $("#signupForm").validate({
        rules: {
            firstname: "required",
            lastname: "required",           
            email: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            },
            topic: {
                required: "#newsletter:checked",
                minlength: 2
            },
            agree: "required"
        },
        messages: {
            firstname: "Please enter your firstname",
            lastname: "Please enter your lastname",
            username: {
                required: "Please enter a username",
                minlength: "Your username must consist of at least 2 characters"
            },
            email: "Please enter a valid email address",
            agree: "Please accept our policy"
        }
    });



});
```

Comment: what validation do you want to add?

Comment: Select list is mandatory. I want to show msg like other fields.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) set an `ID` for `select` tag.

2) create a **default option** with empty string as value.

```
<option value="">select an option</option>
```

---

```
<select id="country" name="country"> <!--SET AN ID-->
        <option value="">select an option</option> <!--DEFAULT OPTION-->
        <option value="Afghanistan">Afghanistan</option>
        <option value="Albania">Albania</option>
        <option value="Algeria">Algeria</option>
        <option value="American Samoa">American Samoa</option>
        <option value="Andorra">Andorra</option>
        <option value="Angola">Angola</option>
        <option value="Anguilla">Anguilla</option>
        <option value="Antarctica">Antarctica</option>
        <option value="Antigua &amp; Barbuda">Antigua &amp; Barbuda</option>
        <option value="Antilles, Netherlands">Antilles, Netherlands</option>
        <option value="Arabia, Saudi">Arabia, Saudi</option>
        <option value="Argentina">Argentina</option>  
</select>
```

In JS, add the below code in `validate` method,

within **`rule`** block

```
country: {
    required: true
 }
```

within `messages` block

```
country: "Please select an option"
```

check this working [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/rw9ns/172/)

**FYI:** mandatory fields should be prefixed or suffixed with `*` to show difference.

Hope you understand.

Comment: @Sowmya I'm glad I was able to help :)

Comment: its not working for me, also fiddle not working, what did I miss

Comment: @meda The external js src used in jsfiddle was expired.  Now I have updated the source.  Take a look http://jsfiddle.net/rw9ns/172/

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is, you have `Afghanistan` selected by default. How it will show required error message when value is present.

Have you considered below simple solution, it works like a charm provided you should have empty value selected. Add `class="required"` to you select tag.

```
<select name="country" class="required">
<option value="">Afghanistan</option>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>

</head>
<body>
<center>
<h2>Registration</h2>
<form  method="get" id="register" action="register.php">
    <table  bgcolor="#CC99FF">
             <tr>
                        <td>Name</td>
                        <td>
                       <input type="text" id="name" name="name" value="" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td>Mobile Number</td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text"  id="mobile" name="mobile" value="" maxlength="10" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td>EmailId</td>
                        <td><input type="text" id="email" name="email" value="" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Gender</td>
                        <td><input type="radio" id="gender" name="gender" value="male" />Male<input type="radio" id="gender" name="gender" value="female" />Female</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Sports</td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" id="hobby" name="hobby[]" value="cricket" />Cricket<input type="checkbox" id="hobby" name="hobby[]" value="tennis" />Tennis<input type="checkbox" id="hobby" name="hobby[]" value="football" />Football</td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td>Stat</td>
                        <td><select name="state" id="state">
                        <option value="0">Please select any one!</option>
                        <option value="Gujarat">Gujarat</option>
                        <option value="Rajastan">Rajastan</option>
                        <option value="Panjab">Panjab</option>
                        <option value="Madya Pradesh">Madya Pradesh</option>
                        </select></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>

                        <td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" /></td>
                    </tr>
                   </table>
</form>
</center>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(e) {
        $("#register").submit(function(e){

            var error=0;
            var name = $("#name").val();
            var mobile = $("#mobile").val();
            var email = $("#email").val();
            var email_pattern = /^[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,3}$/;
            var character_pattern=/^[a-z]+$/;
            var num_pattern=/^[0-9]+$/;

                if(name==""){
                    alert("Please Enter Name");
                    error=1;
                }
                else if(character_pattern.test(name)){
                    //alert("valid name");
                }else{
                    alert("Only Charecter Allowed In Name Field !");
                    error=1;
                }

                if(mobile==""){
                    alert("Please Enter Mobile");
                    error=1;
                }
                else if(num_pattern.test(mobile)){
                    //alert("valid mobile number");
                }else{
                    alert("Only Number Allowed In Mobile Field !");
                    error=1;
                }


                if(email==""){
                    alert("Please Enter email");
                    error=1;
                }
                else if(email_pattern.test(email)){
                    //alert("valid email");
                }else{
                    alert("Please Enter Valid email");
                    $("[name=email]").css("background-color","red");
                    error=1;
                }

                if($("#gender:checked").length == 0)
                {
                    alert("Please Select Any Gender!");
                    error=1;

                }

                if($("#hobby:checked").length == 0)
                {
                    alert("Please Select hobbys!");
                    error=1;

                }

                if( $("#state").val() == '0' )
                {
                    alert("Please Select State!");
                    error=1;

                }

                 if (error) {
                    return false;
                 } else {
                    return true;
                 }
        });

    });

</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. Could you please give some insight as to what this code does, and how it relates to the original question? Working code is all good and well, but without an explanation as to *why* it works it may not be much use to anyone else who reads this answer in the future. See also: [How do I write a good answer?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)